# Select multiple Excel charts

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to select multiple charts in Excel using VBA.

It can be done by using `.Select` on `ChatObject` but I cannot select multiple charts like that. If I have multiple charts in `ActiveSheet` every time I use `.Select` I select only the "last" chart and unselect previous chart.

How can I select multiple charts that satisfy my condition (whatever it is)? Or, how to add new selection to previously selected items?

```
Sub select_charts()

Dim chtObjs As ChartObjects
Set chtObjs = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

Dim chtObj As ChartObject
For Each chtObj In chtObjs
    If chtObj.Height > 100 Then
        chtObj.Select
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Please, try something like that: `ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Chart 1", "Chart 2")).Select`. You can use the loop to place the `chartObjects` name in the array to be used.

Comment: Your idea was exactly what I was missing. Please post it as answer and I will gladly accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA is able to select more objects using an array containing the objects Names, or their indexes.

1. The simplest way, answering your question is:

```
 ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Chart 1", "Chart 2")).Select
```

2. You can build such an array (using some conditions) and finally use it for selection:

```
Sub testSelectCharts()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, s As Shape, arrChObj(), arrChIndex(), i As Long, k As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  ReDim arrChObj(sh.Shapes.count - 1)    'ReDim the array to be sure that it has enough elements
  ReDim arrChIndex(sh.Shapes.count - 1)  'ReDim the array to be sure that it has enough elements
  For Each s In sh.Shapes                'iterate between all shapes
    i = i + 1                            'the shape index
    If TypeOf s.OLEFormat.Object Is ChartObject Then 'act only for chart objects:
        arrChIndex(k) = i               'loading an array of shapes index
        arrChObj(k) = s.Name: k = k + 1 'loading an array of shapes name
    End If
  Next
  ReDim Preserve arrChObj(k - 1)        'preserving only the array elements containing values
  ReDim Preserve arrChIndex(k - 1)      'preserving only the array elements containing values
  sh.Shapes.Range(arrChObj).Select      'selecting using array object names  
  'sh.Shapes.Range(arrChIndex).Select   'it works using sheet indexes, too (just uncomment and comment the above code line)
End Sub
```

3. You can select/activate sheets in the next way:

```
Sub testSheetsSelect()
  Worksheets(Array(Sheets(1).Name, Sheets(3).Name)).Select
  'Worksheets(Array(1, 3)).Select     'using an array of sheets indexes
End Sub
```

4. The next testing sub selects sheet ActiveX controls of type "CommandButton". Of course, the active sheet should have at least one such a control and some others, of different type (combo box, list box etc.):

```
Sub testObjectsNameArray()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, objOLE As OLEObject, arrOLE(), k As Long

  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  ReDim arrOLE(sh.OLEObjects.count - 1)
  For Each objOLE In sh.OLEObjects
    If TypeOf objOLE.Object Is MSForms.CommandButton Then
        arrOLE(k) = objOLE.Name: k = k + 1
    End If
  Next
  ReDim Preserve arrOLE(k - 1)
  sh.OLEObjects(arrOLE).Select
End Sub
```

The array of indexes should also work...